# Database Design for a Questionnaire

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, database-schema

I have a database of 100-200 topics with 20 questions in each topic. Each question can have multiple parameters (max 7) and can go into multiple sets (max 20). The division of questions into sets is done manually. I have to store this into the database. I am thinking on following lines:

Make a table for storing the questions having the schema as:
topic_id, question_id,question,sets,parameters,correct_answer

sets column will store like 1,2,3,4..
parameters column will store like a,b,c,d..

I have not worked with multiple value fields before and I don't know if it will be feasible as I will have more than 4000 rows at some point.

Comment: 4000 rows is tiny.  Don't worry about that.  Just go by answers to the following.  Is it conceivable for the same question to appear in more than one topic?  Is it conceiveable for the same answer to be offered in more than one question?  If a question appears in more than one topic, is it conceivable that it would have a different set of answers?  In any event, you do not want to store lists.  You want many to many relationships.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comma-separated value fields are difficult to use in selections and to maintain.  Instead it is better to use multiple tables.  Specifically, you would have a QuestionSets table (sets that questions belong to) and QuestionParameter table.

Questions would have

- question_id
- topic_id,
- question
- answer (is it multiple choice?)

Then you would have Sets/Parameters with ID and other values.  The mapping tables would reference both IDs

```
QuestionSets
question_id | set_id
```